# User editable countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timertask

Let me start by I do not know javascript( I am watching videos online, reading books, udemy workshop) but building my first website. I want to be able to have an countdown timer that any user can edit but I only need minutes and seconds.

I have a marker on a map (106) that i want the timer in and a person can click on marker, it pops up a timer that is either in countdown or needs to have one started. If someone leaves the page the countdown continues until 0.

Does anyone know where I can find something like this?

Thank you for you help!

```
var marker96 = L.marker([41.974591, -91.655211]).addTo(mymap);
marker96.bindPopup("You Are A Stranger").openPopup();
```

Comment: [tag:timertask] tag pertains to a Java API, not JavaScript. And `L` is not a vanilla JavaScript value. Furthermore, what you ask is not a trivial task, involving a server component, AJAX or WebSockets, plus knowledge of whatever library you are using; it is not in scope of a Stack Overflow answer (which is really for fixing problems, not for getting ready-made solutions).

Comment: Well thank you for criticizing me for asking a question on where I can learn this. I did not ask for someone to do the work for me but simply asked if anyone knew where I could find the answer as I am new to this.